# Communicating variables from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to pass a value from JavaScript to PHP whenever I click a button.
For example, the value of the `getdate()` will be passed on to PHP.

Which will then be used to manipulate the database.

Comment: Please take a look at ajax. When you click a button, you can have javascript `get` a PHP connector page, the page can then insert values into the database.

Answer (score 3):

1. Attach an event handler function to the button click event.
2. Make an ajax call in this function, sending the value to the server-side PHP script.